# Converting cURL command with XML string to python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I was used to send XML strings to the API of my firewall with this cURL command:

```
curl -k https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController -F "reqxml=<myfile.xml"
```

Now, I would like to do this in python. Since the XML string will be created programmatically, I don't provide a XML file but a XML string.
This is my code right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

def xml_string():
    return '''
    reqxml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Request>
        <Login>
            <Username>admin</Username>
            <Password>admin</Password>
        </Login>
        <Set>
        … further markup …
        </Set>
    </Request>
    '''

def send_xml():
  response = requests.post(
    "https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"},
    data=xml_string(),
    verify=False
    )
  print(response.status_code)


send_xml()
```

The output of the verbose command `curl -k -v https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController -F "reqxml=<testcategory.xml"` is:

```
* Trying 192.1.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.1.1.1 (192.1.1.1) port 90 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=NA …
*  start date: Aug  1 00:00:00 2010 GMT
*  expire date: Dec 31 23:59:59 2030 GMT
*  issuer: C=NA …
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
> POST /APIController HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.1.1.1:90
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 796
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------20be8a5c28d38998
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2020 10:07:59 GMT
< Server: xxxx
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/xml;  charset=UTF-8
< Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
< Expires: Tue, 26 May 2020 10:07:59 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response APIVersion="1702.1" IPS_CAT_VER="1">
  <Login>
    <status>Authentication Successful</status>
  </Login>
  <Status code="200">Configuration applied successfully.</Status>
</Response>
* Connection #0 to host 192.1.1.1 left intact
```

But despite the returned status code is 200, the command had no effect on the firewall, no settings were changed. Why doesn't work the python code as expected?

EDIT:
I found out, that the XML string is completely ignored when firing the above python code. Maybe this **working** code in PHP can shed some light?

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <Login>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
    </Login>
    <Set>
    …
    </Set>
</Request>';
$url = "https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "reqxml=" . $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($data);
echo '</pre>';
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print curl_error($ch);
} else {
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Comment: amend your question & paste your curl -v command output.

Comment: have you also looked at the data returned by the remote endpoint? perhaps there's an error string and the status code is 200. Have a look at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Comment: I added the verbose output to my original question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/113962 for an example of how to upload a file with requests. Try getting it to work with an actual file first, then once that’s working you can use stringio instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to compare what is sent over the wire using a tool/application that changes the actual setting and compare with your python requests request. If your remote host accepts plain HTTP, use that & fire up wireshark/tcpdump

---edit

1. Try post the content as a file using requests library.

```py
xml_content = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request>
    <Login>
        <Username>admin</Username>
        <Password>admin</Password>
    </Login>
    <Set>
    …
    </Set>
</Request>
'''
url = "https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController"

files = {'file': ('reqxml', xml_content)}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Comment: This seems to be beyond my technical skills. Could you give some hints where I can get more information about this? Unfortunately, my host doesn't accept plain HTTP.

Comment: You need to use a POST with content-type multipart/form-data or 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. That means you either upload a file or submit a form. Try change your content type to 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of "application/xml"

Comment: Thank you, but changing Content-type and base64-encoding of the XML-part didn't work neither.

Comment: instead of data=... try files=... as seen in the last example of: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: your last edit seemed logic and promising, but for some reason it doesn't work. Command `print(r.url)` outputs just `https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController` without any values …

Answer (score 0):

To do it simply, you could try to execute the `curl` command directly through python.
Store the xml string to a file.xml

```
import os
os.system('curl -k https://192.1.1.1:90/APIController -F "reqxml=<<path to file.xml>"')
```

(Updated)OR

Based on your `curl` command output as well as the `php` code, it looks like the content type is being sent as `multipart/form-data`. Maybe you could try to using the same `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with the payload converted to `"reqxml=" + "base64 encoded xml data"`

Comment: I am aware of this work around, but the task has to be done with python only.

Comment: Thank you, but changing Content-type and base64-encoding of the XML-part didn't work neither.

Comment: Did you try adding an `Accept: 'text/xml'` header and sending the data as mentioned here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689393/how-to-perform-an-http-xml-authentication-with-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689393/how-to-perform-an-http-xml-authentication-with-requests)

Comment: Adding `Accept: 'text/xml` to the header doesn't help.